# JSONDecorderError: Expecting Value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to create a simple chatbot with the following contents of the following JSON file

> `{ "body": "And the reply because it's not where it was
>   earlier:\nhttps://twitter.com/Ethantaylor/status/1182878776612544512?s=20",
>       "score_hidden": null,
>       "archived": null,
>       "name": null,
>       "author": "DomHaynie",
>       "author_flair_text": null,
>       "downs": null,
>       "created_utc": "1570924814",
>       "subreddit_id": "t5_33x33",
>       "link_id": "t3_dgp0o1",
>       "parent_id": "t1_f3hk153",
>       "score": "2",
>       "retrieved_on": "1578913258",
>       "controversiality": "0",
>       "gilded": "0",
>       "id": "f3hk4gq",
>       "subreddit": "BlackPeopleTwitter",
>       "ups": null,
>       "distinguished": null,
>       "author_flair_css_class": null   }`

I tried loading the file but unfortunately, it's throwing an error I'm not aware of. This is the code I have so far:

```
#create table#
def create_table():
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_reply(parent_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, comment_id TEXT UNIQUE, parent TEXT, comment TEXT, subreddit TEXT, unix INT, score INT)""")

#format the data to exclude \n characters and double quotation marks"
def format_data(data):
              data = data.replace("\n"," newlinechar ").replace("\r"," newlinechar ").replace('"',"'")
              return data    
def find_parent(pid):
    try:
              sql = "select comment from parent_reply where comment_id ='{}' limit 1".format(pid)
              c.execute(sql)
              result = c.fetchone()
              if result != None:
                  return result[0]
              else: return False
    except Exception as e:
              #print("find_parent",e)
              return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
              create_table()
              row_counter = 0
              paired_rows = 0

              with open("/mnt/bcache0/home/hsheraz/notebooks/Reddit_comments/{}-10/RC_{}".format(timeframe.split('-')[0], timeframe), buffering = 1000) as f:
                       for row in f:
                            print(row)
                            row_counter += 1
                            row = json.loads(row)
                            #parent_id = row['parent_id']
```

But I keep running into this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-2aa65204200c> in <module>()
     31                             print(row)
     32                             row_counter += 1
---> 33                             row = json.loads(row)
     34                             #parent_id = row['parent_id']
     35                             #body = format_data(row['body'])

/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    317             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    318             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 319         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    320     if cls is None:
    321         cls = JSONDecoder

/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

There were some answers posted in the past but I am not quite sure how to solve it. I am new to python and so still not aware of most of the errors.

Comment: I verified the contents of the json file and it seems correct. Not too sure what the problem is

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for this kind of additional info - edit & update your question instead. Also, question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `tensorflow` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).